# Implementing JSF 2.0 with JBoss 4.x

Tags: jsf-2, jboss, jsf-1.2

I am currently working on upgrading JSF version from 1.2 to 2.0 for an application deployed in JBoss 4.3.0. I am still quite new to JBoss and I encountering this problem. I have downloaded the JSF jars (impl and api) and put the under jboss-web.deployer/jsf-libs. I have also put the richfaces-impl jar in C:\Program Files\Java\richfaces-ui-3.3.3.Final\lib.

When I start the server, I don't get any error in the console, but I am unable to navigate through the site. Internet Explorer gives an error saying 'Mojarra not defined'. On comparing the output .html files of the version with jsf 2.0 jars and that with 1.2, I noticed that the function in onclick attribute has 'mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById' for JSF 2.0 while for 1.2 it has 'var b=function(){if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.getElementById'.

How is this output file generated? Will it work if I can get the output files to have the same function? If not, then how can I solve the 'mojarra not defined' problem? I am working on MyEclipse Enterprise Workbench Version 8.0. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

JSF 2.0 will not work in Jboss 4.x and even in Jboss 5.x
You need to upgrade your Jboss to 6.x or above. You can refer this [link](https://community.jboss.org/message/595333#595333). That said, one can make JSF 2.x run on Jboss lower versions like 5.x by placing jars in Jboss lib folder. But, that is not recommended and should not be done.

Answer (score 0):

I use Mojarra implementation of JSF 2 on Jboss 4.2.2.

you need to specify in your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.WAR_BUNDLES_JSF_IMPL</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

You need also to provide into your war jsf lib that you what to use.
Let me know if it's ok on Jboss 4.3.0

Comment: Hey thanks! But it still does not work. Still the same error, mojarra is not defined. I changed the version of faces-config.xml, commented out the view_handler part from web.xml and faces-config.xml and removed the jsf-facelets.jar from WEB-INF\lib and now when I start go to the url it gives the following error:

Comment: 09:58:35,026 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:58:35,026 ERROR [BaseXMLFilter] Exception in the filter chain
javax.servlet.ServletException: Orchestra was unable to create an instance of bean with name 'AccessScopeManager'. Ensure that JSF variable resolution uses your dependency injection (DI) framework (eg Spring's DelegatingVariableResolver is in your faces-config.xml file) and the standard Orchestra configuration beans are defined (eg by using <import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/spring-orchestra-init.xml" />).
 at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:325)

Comment: Ok, go to `\server\default\deploy\jboss-web.deployer\conf` and edit the web.xml file. Comment lines about JSF  `<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.injectionProvider</param-name>`, 
     `<listener-class>org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.config.JBossJSFConfigureListener</listener-class>` and  `<listener>
     <listener-class>com.sun.faces.application.WebappLifecycleListener` and remove from your web.xml of your webbApps `<param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.WAR_BUNDLES_JSF_IMPL</param-name>`,

Comment: remplace also in `server\default\deploy\jboss-web.deployer\jsf-libs` jsf jars (don't forget to rename jar with the initial name)